# No Code Coverage on Apex Class

Tags: unit-test

I have an Apex Class where none of the lines are being covered by my test class. The test class is passing and I'm getting the results I expect. I also checked the box "Always Run Asynchronously" but still no luck. The Apex Class is not called from a Trigger. How can I link these two up?

```
public with sharing class DisplayInventoryController {    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<ProductItem> getProductItemsBySTM(Id recordId) {
        String stmId = recordId;

        //get the ST ID from the STM, then get the LocationID from the STL
        ServiceTerritoryMember stm = [SELECT Id, ServiceTerritoryId FROM ServiceTerritoryMember WHERE Id = :stmId];
        ServiceTerritoryLocation stl = [SELECT Id, LocationId FROM ServiceTerritoryLocation WHERE ServiceTerritoryId = :stm.ServiceTerritoryId];
        
        //Get the list of Product Items
        List<ProductItem> piList = [SELECT  ProductItemNumber, ProductName, QuantityOnHand, Quantity_Remaining__c, Quantity_Reserved__c 
                                     FROM ProductItem 
                                     WHERE LocationId = :stl.LocationId];
                                     
        for (ProductItem pi : piList){
            if(pi.Quantity_Reserved__c ==NULL){
                pi.Quantity_Reserved__c=0;
            }
        }
        return piList;
    }
}
```

Here is the Test class:

```
@isTest
private class DisplayInventoryController_Test {
      
    @isTest
    static void getServiceTerritoryLocation()
    {   
        DisplayInventoryController dic = new DisplayInventoryController();

        ServiceTerritoryLocation stLocation = new ServiceTerritoryLocation();        
            stLocation.Test_Name__c = 'Test Data';
            stLocation.LocationId = '131r00000000B1gAAE';
            stLocation.ServiceTerritoryId = '0Hhr00000000A5kCAE'; 
        
        Test.startTest();
          insert stLocation;
        Test.stopTest();
        
        //Check if data was inserted as expected
        List<ServiceTerritoryLocation> stl = [SELECT Id, Test_Name__c, LocationId FROM ServiceTerritoryLocation];
        System.debug(stl);
        System.assertEquals('131r00000000B1gAAE', stLocation.LocationId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your test must directly call the method i.e.:

```
// This must be the Id of a ServiceTerritoryMember record
Id stmId = ...;

List<ProductItem> items = DisplayInventoryController.getProductItemsBySTM(stmId);

// Assert number of and content of items
```

Ideally you would add an extra `@isTest` focussed on this method.

As `getProductItemsBySTM` is a `static` method you do not need to `new` an instance of the containing class.

Comment: I added these 2 lines below the DisplayInventoryController constructor.

Id stmId = '0Hur000000006THCAY';
List<ProductItem> products = DisplayInventoryController.getProductItemsBySTM(stmId); 

I also tried to populate the "products" list, which did not work, so I created a new List<ProductItem> and tried to insert it. The good news is that it's reading the first 3 lines of the Apex Class. The bad news is i'm getting the error "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject"